# Make4ht with % in the Caption

Tags: tex4ht, make4ht

The below LaTeX file is working fine with `pdflatex` and showing error in `make4ht`. How to recetify this? When I have used `%` in the figure captions it's writing in the `aux` file and show error.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title}

\lipsum[3]

Nominal data are usually used with count and frequencies, such as to find out the total number of left-handed participants in a study. Figure~\hyperref[fig-001]{1.1} illustrates an excerpt from a questionnaire that collected nominal data.

\begin{figure*}
\caption{Excerpt 95\% from a questionnaire used in an actual user study of Section~\ref{sec:1} and Subsection~\ref{subsec:1-1} to collect nominal \index{demographics} data [\protect\hyperlink{ch2-ref48}{Shang et\,\,al. 2020}].\label{fig-001}}
\end{figure*}

With this approach, the lowest, the middle, and the highest points of the actual scale are anchored to the lowest, the middle, and the highest points of the target scale, respectively, then the intervening scale points are inserted at equal numerical intervals.

The European Union-wide framework known as the General Data Protection Regulation \footnote{{\href{https://ec.europa.eu/commission/priorities/justice-and-fundamental-rights/data-protection/2018-reform-eu-data-protection-rules_en}{https://ec.europa.eu/commission/priorities/justice-and-fundamental-rights/data-protection/2018-reform-eu-data-protection-rules{\_}en}.}} EU approach data privacy. The purpose of GDPR is to protect personal data at large.

\end{document}
```

[image]

UPDATE 2:

`\ref` and `\index` also showing error when using `make4ht`. Please see updated the question in the `\caption`.

Comment: Which version of tex4ht do you use? When I try your example I don't get errors and the output looks ok (i.e., the caption is rendered as "Excerpt 95% from ..."). (command: `make4ht -u myfile.tex`, the `-u` is to render non-breaking spaces produced by `~` properly and is unrelated to `\%`). My version is `make4ht version v0.3d` and tex4ht itself is `tex4ht.c (2018-07-03-10:36 kpathsea)`, from TeX Live 2019.

Comment: Also, if you get an error, what is the exact error message?

Comment: @Marijn: I have using `Make4HT Version is v0.3l` and `TeX4HT Version is tex4ht.c (2018-07-03-10:36 kpathsea)` and used `Windows OS`. I have updated `Error Screenshot` in the Question.

Comment: @Marijn: If you are check with `myfile.aux` file it will show `95% from a` instead of `95\% from a`.

Comment: Your output shows an error on line 862. The code you have given in this question does not have 862 lines. Therefore the error is most probably in a part of the code that you didn't provide. Please test with the exact code as you have given here.

Comment: @Marijn:  I don't have 862 line. My LaTeX file is having only `18 lines` and provided in the `question`. If, I have removed all the unwanted files and only `test1.tex` file in the folder. Now it's showing `1ST COMPILE ERROR is` :: `{{\rEfLiNK {{x1-10011}{\csname :autoref\endcsname {figure*}1.1}}{\rEfLiNK \ETC.` `! File ended while scanning use of \newlabel.` `2ND COMPILE ERROR is` :: `{{\rEfLiNK {{x1-10011}{\csname :autoref\endcsname {figure*}1.1}}{\rEfLiNK \ETC.` `! File ended while scanning use of \n:wlbl.` NOTE: `\n:wlbl` and `\newlabel`.

Comment: @Marijn: I have used `LaTeXMK -c` and `Make4HT -m Clean filename` for cleaning unwanted files.

Comment: In that case it looks like there is indeed a bug. Did you try to remove the `\%` to see if that actually works, to confirm that the problem is indeed the percent sign? You can also consider filing a bug report on https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht/.

Comment: @Marijn: Yes. It's working fine without `\%` in the caption. I will fill the bug to michal.

Comment: I can confirm that this is a bug. I've already found a fix and will update TeX4ht sources.

Comment: Regarding the problems with `\ref`: this seems like a different problem, please ask a new question about this.

Comment: @Marijn: This problem same in `\caption` only and it's compiling fine with `pdflatex` and only error showing in `make4ht`.

Comment: @Balaji the cause of the problem and the solution are probably different though, because things like `\ref` and `\index` are more complicated to process (inside and outside of captions), also in LaTeX itself. Even when questions are closely related we prefer to have one issue per question on the site.

Comment: @Marijn: I have posted new question <https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/653084/make4ht-with-ref-and-index-in-the-caption>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue seems to be caused by the definition of the `\%` command in TeX4ht sources. You can revert it to the original definition, which seems to work using the following config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\chardef\%=`\%
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: It's showing `Section~\ref{sec:1}` and `\index` also error when using `Make4HT` and not showing error in `pdflatex`.  ERROR IS : `! File ended while scanning use of \n:wlbl.`. How to rectify this also?

Comment: @Balaji I cannot reproduce this problem, can you update your question?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: I have posted new question <https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/653084/make4ht-with-ref-and-index-in-the-caption>