# Make4ht with \ref and \index in the Caption

Tags: tex4ht, make4ht

The below file compile fine with `pdflatex` and showing error in `make4ht`. How to rectify this?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title}

\section{Introduction}\label{sec:1}

Nominal data are usually used with count and frequencies, such as to find out the total number of left-handed participants in a study. Figure~\hyperref[fig-001]{1.1} illustrates an excerpt from a questionnaire that collected nominal data.

\subsection{Background}\label{subsec:1-1}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{figure*}
\caption{Excerpt 95\% from a questionnaire used in an actual user study of Section~\ref{sec:1} and Subsection~\ref{subsec:1-1} to collect nominal \index{demographics} data [\protect\hyperlink{ch2-ref48}{Shang et\,\,al. 2020}].\label{fig-001}}
\end{figure*}

With this approach, the lowest, the middle, and the highest points of the actual scale are anchored to the lowest, the middle, and the highest points of the target scale, respectively, then the intervening scale points are inserted at equal numerical intervals.

The European Union-wide framework known as the General Data Protection Regulation \footnote{{\href{https://ec.europa.eu/commission/priorities/justice-and-fundamental-rights/data-protection/2018-reform-eu-data-protection-rules_en}{https://ec.europa.eu/commission/priorities/justice-and-fundamental-rights/data-protection/2018-reform-eu-data-protection-rules{\_}en}.}} EU approach data privacy.

\end{document}
```

UPDATE1:

[image]

UPDATE2:

`Figure 1.1` questionnaire should be `Figure <a href='#fig1.1'>1.1</a>` questionnaire. It means `caption` `cross-links` are missing.

Comment: Thanks for posting the new question. What is the error message that you get with `make4ht`? If you can, please paste the error as text in a code block and not an an image.

Comment: LaTeX1 Compile Error is: `[ERROR]   htlatex: ./test1.tex  862      File ended while scanning use of \newlabel.`
LaTeX2 Compile Error is: `[ERROR]   htlatex: ./test1.tex  862      File ended while scanning use of \n:wlbl. [ERROR]   htlatex: ./test1.tex  3        File ended while scanning use of \:testdef.`

Comment: @JohnKormylo: I have needed the `figure caption` in the `\listoffigures` also. How to avoid this error using `duplicate`. could you please provide the command?

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  Try deleting the aux file and try again.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Yes, It's working fine after deleting `aux` file. But when using `make4ht` without `-m draft` option it's running 3 times and showing error. But the output HTML is having `cross link` is working fine.

Comment: this file compiles fine for me when I use the configuration file from your previous question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/652950/2891

Comment: @michal.h21: But I have get the ERROR with `cfg` and without `cfg`. Please find the error snapshot in the question.

Comment: Maybe try to delete the .aux file and then compile again with the config file

Comment: @michal.h21: I have updated `tlmgr update --all` and it's now working fine not showing any error. But in the `html` file `section 1.1` and `subsection 1.1.1` `span` (hyperlink) is missing and it's possible to get the output same as figure like `<span class=id'>Figure 1.1</span>`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean,can you show what is missing?

Comment: @michal.h21: I have updated the question. You can see Figure 1.1 is having `<span class='id'>` tag and `Section 1.1` is not having `<span>` tag.

Comment: I think that what is missing is the `<figure>` environment with an id. It is caused by the `figure*` environment, which doesn't have extra configuration in TeX4ht. I will add it to the sources, and can send it's definition as the answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there was no configuration for the `figure*` environment in TeX4ht, so you don't get correct HTML tags in this case. I've fixed this issue in TeX4ht sources. Until this change comes to TeX Live, you can use the following configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\ConfigureEnv{figure*}
{\IgnorePar\EndP\HCode{<figure class="figure">\Hnewline}%
    \bgroup \Configure{float}{\ShowPar}{}{}%
   }
   {\egroup
   \IgnorePar\EndP\HCode{</figure>}\ShowPar
\par}
   {}{}

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This is the resulting HTML code for your figure:

```html
   <figure class='figure' id='-excerpt-from-a-questionnaire-used-in-an-actual-user-study-of-section-ref-sec-and-subsection-ref-subsec-to-collect-nominal-data-chrefshang-etal-'>                                                                 
<a id='x1-30011'></a>                                                         
<figcaption class='caption'><span class='id'>Figure 1.1: </span><span class='content'>Excerpt 95% from a questionnaire used in an actual user study of
Section 1.1  and Subsection 1.1.1  to collect nominal  data [<a href='#ch2-ref48'>Shang et al. 2020</a>].</span></figcaption><!-- tex4ht:label?: x1-30011  -->                                                           
   </figure>
```